# cypress 12.13.0 webpack compilation error when accessing import.meta using ts-loader

Tags: webpack, babeljs, cypress

Webpack compilation error in Cypress when using import.meta.

I'm using Vue 3, typescript and Quasar 2 framework with vite build tool and Cypress 12.13.0 as e2e testing tool.
I Quasar 2 I got 2 boot files, one for axios, one for authorization. Everything works fine when starting the quasar devServer or build the application using vite build tool.
When I start the e2etests implemented in Cypress, that does the build using webpack I get an error in my auth.ts boot file when trying to access import.meta. In my axios boot file I'm accessing import.meta and it works fine. I can't figure out the differences but I suspect it has something to do with the modules I import that have implications on the transpile of the code from typescript to javascript. Here is the Cypress error when starting a test:

```
    Error: Webpack Compilation Error
    ./src/boot/auth.ts 4:29
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:29)
    File was processed with these loaders:
     * ../../.cache/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/node_modules/ts-loader/index.js
    You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
    | import { WebStorageStateStore } from 'oidc-client';
    | import { createOidcAuth, SignInType, LogLevel } from 'vue-oidc-client/vue3';
    > console.log('xxxxxxx', import.meta.env);
    | const appRootUrl = (new URL(import.meta.url)).origin.concat('/');
    | const identityProvider = import.meta.env.VITE_MIRA_OIDC_AUTHORITY;
     @ ./test/cypress/support/commands.ts 31:0-40 47:4-13 51:4-13 55:4-13 59:4-13
     @ ./test/cypress/support/e2e.ts
        at Watching.handle [as handler] (/data/xxxxxxx/.cache/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-preprocessor/dist/index.js:212:23)
        at /data/xxxxxxx/.cache/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:99:9
        at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/data/xxxxxxx/.cache/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
        at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/data/xxxxxxx/.cache/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
        at Watching._done (/data/xxxxxxx/.cache/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:98:28)
        at /data/xxxxxxx/.cache/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:73:19
        at Compiler.emitRecords (/data/xxxxxxx/.cache/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:499:39)
        at /data/xxxxxxx/.cache/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:54:20
        at /data/xxxxxxx/.cache/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:485:14
        at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/data/xxxxxxx/.cache/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
        at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/data/xxxxxxx/.cache/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
        at /data/xxxxxxx/.cache/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:482:27
        at /data/xxxxxxx/.cache/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2818:7
        at done (/data/xxxxxxx/.cache/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3522:9)
        at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/data/xxxxxxx/.cache/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
        at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/data/xxxxxxx/.cache/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
        at /data/xxxxxxx/.cache/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:464:33
        at /data/xxxxxxx/.cache/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:143:16
        at /data/xxxxxxx/.cache/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:143:16
        at /data/xxxxxxx/.cache/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:61:14
        at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:192:23)
```

This is the axios.ts boot files start where import.meta works fine:

```
    import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers';
    import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
    
    declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
      interface ComponentCustomProperties {
        $axios: AxiosInstance;
      }
    }
    const api = axios.create({
      baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_MIRA_API_URI,
      responseType: 'json',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        charset: 'utf-8',
      },
    });
```

This is the auth.ts boot files start where import.meta fails:

```
    import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers';
    import { User, WebStorageStateStore } from 'oidc-client';
    import { createOidcAuth, SignInType, LogLevel, OidcAuth } from 'vue-oidc-client/vue3';
    
    console.log('xxxxxxx', import.meta.env)    <<<<- here is where it fails
    
    declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
      interface ComponentCustomProperties {
        $oidc: OidcAuth;
      }
    }
    
    const appRootUrl = (new URL(import.meta.url)).origin.concat('/');
    const identityProvider = import.meta.env.VITE_MIRA_OIDC_AUTHORITY;
    const clientID = import.meta.env.VITE_MIRA_OIDC_CLIENT_ID;
    
    const idsrvAuth = createOidcAuth(
        'main',
        SignInType.Window,
        appRootUrl,
        {
          authority: identityProvider,
          client_id: clientID,
          response_type: 'code',
          scope: 'openid',
          userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: localStorage }),
        },
        console,
        LogLevel.Debug
      );
```

Any ideas why import.meta is available in axios.ts boot file but isn't in auth.ts boot file?

Thx for any advice.

I tried to figure out if it has something to to with the configuration of the babel transpilation and different babel.config.js files for the imported modules but couldn't figure it out.